Why does the swipe display the elements in a row?
I need to display a slider with tabs in 4 rows of 3 elements, the documentation states that elements are drawn by column by default, but for some reason my elements are displayed in rows, to be honest I have no idea what I can try, please help!
Initialized the slider
 var swiper = new Swiper('.sample_slider', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        loopAddBlankSlides : true,
        // spaceBetween: 20,
        grid:
            {
                fill: 'column',
                rows:4,
            },

        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        },



    });


  <div class="container">
            <p class="h2 _serv"><?= Loc::getMessage("TITLE"); ?></p>
            <div class="swiper sample_slider">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <? foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $index_cur => $arItem) {?>

                    <div class="swiper-slide _1">
                                <div class="list_services__item"
                                     data-tab="<?= $arItem["CODE"] ?>">
                                    <?= $arItem["NAME"] ?>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                        <?}?>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev tab_btn"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next tab_btn"></div>
                <div class="swiper-pagination pagination"></div>
                </div>

            </div>

Perhaps the problem is in the styles?
.sample_slider .swiper-slide{      
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: calc((50% - 30px) / 2) !important;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.list_services__item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   width: 407px;
    height: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 100%), #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #AE9483, 0px -1px 11px 0px rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.25);
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #464646;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}


Please move your minimal working code to some online code editor and share the URL.
